# python tkinter move items from one frame to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have 2 lists of items available items and active items, I am initially adding the items into the available list from a dictionary. I would like to activate items and move them from the available list into the active list when the associated activate button is pressed (this should also remove the item from the available list) if the remove item button is then pressed I would like to remove the item from the active list and put it back into the available list. I cannot figure out how to do this, I am pretty sure I need a list of the widgets instead of simply using the dictionary items but I am struggling to understand how this would work.

Here is what I have so far:-

```
import tkinter as tk    

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Add Remove Items Example")
        self.geometry("800x450")

        self.items = {
            "Item 1": "Item 1 Description",
            "Item 2": "Item 2 Description",
            "Item 3": "Item 3 Description",
        }

        self.active_items = []
        self.available_items = []

        # Available Items
        self.available_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.available_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        if len(self.items) == 0:
            tk.Label(self.available_frame, text="No Items Available").grid(
                row=0, column=0
            )
        else:
            for item in self.items:
                item_frame = tk.Frame(self)
                item_frame.grid(row=len(self.available_items), column=0)

                tk.Label(item_frame, text=item).grid(row=0, column=0)
                tk.Label(item_frame, text=self.items[item]).grid(row=1, column=0)
                tk.Button(
                    item_frame,
                    text="Activate",
                    command=lambda item=item: self.activate_item(item),
                ).grid(row=0, rowspan=2, column=1)

                self.available_items.append(item)

        # Active Items

        self.active_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.active_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
        if len(self.active_items) == 0:
            tk.Label(self.active_frame, text="No Items Active").grid(row=0, column=0)

    def activate_item(self, item):
        print(f"Add {item}")
        tk.Label(self.active_frame, text=item).grid(
            row=len(self.active_items), column=0
        )
        tk.Button(
            self.active_frame,
            text="Remove",
            command=lambda item=item: self.remove_item(item),
        ).grid(row=len(self.active_items), column=1)
        self.active_items.append(item)

    def remove_item(self, item):
        print(f"Remove {item}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

can anybody give me any tips on how to improve this further adding the above functionality?

EDIT

I have continued to work on this and have come up with a workable solution:

```
import tkinter as tk


class ItemFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        # Added an index for the row as len would overwrite the last item in
        # the list if the first item was activated and then removed again it would
        # be better to remove this if I can redraw the full list in ascending order
        self.row = 0

        self.label_list = []
        self.button_list = []

        # label if no items in this list, need to figure out how to add list name
        # i.e "No Available Items"/"No Active Items" I will probably pass this in
        self.no_items = tk.Label(
            self,
            text="No Items",
        )
        self.no_items.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def add_item(self, item, action):
        self.no_items.grid_forget()
        label = tk.Label(
            self,
            text=item,
        )
        button = tk.Button(
            self,
            text=action,
            command=lambda: self.button_event(item, action),
        )

        label.grid(row=self.row, column=0)
        button.grid(row=self.row, column=1)
        self.label_list.append(label)
        self.button_list.append(button)
        self.row += 1

    def remove_item(self, item):
        for label, button in zip(self.label_list, self.button_list):
            if item == label.cget("text"):
                label.destroy()
                button.destroy()
                self.label_list.remove(label)
                self.button_list.remove(button)
        if len(self.label_list) == 0:
            self.row = 0
            self.no_items.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def button_event(self, item, action):
        self.remove_item(item)
        self.parent.button_event(item, action)


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Add Remove Items Example")
        self.geometry("800x450")

        # create available frame
        self.available_frame = ItemFrame(self)
        self.available_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # populate with dummy data
        for i in range(5):
            self.available_frame.add_item(f"available item {i}", "Activate")

        # create active frame
        self.active_frame = ItemFrame(self)
        self.active_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)

    def button_event(self, item, action):
        if action == "Activate":
            self.active_frame.add_item(item, "Remove")
        elif action == "Remove":
            self.available_frame.add_item(item, "Activate")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

I would prefer it if I could insert the items into the opposite list/frame in alphabetical/numerical order and redraw the full list but I think that is way outside of my abilities and don't know where to start. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to hold the active state of the items and populate those items to corresponding frame based on their active state:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Add Remove Items Example")
        self.geometry("800x450")

        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure((0,1), weight=1, uniform=1)

        self.itemlist = {
            "Item 1": "Item 1 Description",
            "Item 2": "Item 2 Description",
            "Item 3": "Item 3 Description",
        }

        # all items are not activated initially
        self.items = {item:False for item in self.itemlist}

        # Frame holding available items
        self.available_frame = tk.Frame(self, bd=1, relief="sunken")
        self.available_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

        # Frame holding activated items
        self.active_frame = tk.Frame(self, bd=1, relief="sunken")
        self.active_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")

        self.refresh_lists()

    def clear_frame(self, frame):
        for w in frame.winfo_children():
            w.destroy()

    def refresh_lists(self):
        # clear the two frames
        self.clear_frame(self.available_frame)
        self.clear_frame(self.active_frame)
        # populate items to corresponding frame
        active_cnt = available_cnt = 0
        for item, activated in self.items.items():
            if activated:
                tk.Label(self.active_frame, text=f"{item}\n{self.itemlist[item]}")\
                    .grid(row=active_cnt, column=0)
                tk.Button(self.active_frame, text="Remove", command=lambda item=item: self.activate_item(item, False))\
                    .grid(row=active_cnt, column=1)
                active_cnt += 1
            else:
                tk.Label(self.available_frame, text=f"{item}\n{self.itemlist[item]}")\
                    .grid(row=available_cnt, column=0)
                tk.Button(self.available_frame, text="Activate", command=lambda item=item: self.activate_item(item, True))\
                    .grid(row=available_cnt, column=1)
                available_cnt += 1

    def activate_item(self, item, state):
        print(f"Activate {item} {state}")
        self.items[item] = state
        self.refresh_lists()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a much better solution than my workaround